# DRBD server not starting - error in creating netlink socket

Tags: networking, nfs, software-raid, ubuntu-14.04, drbd

I have a newly configured DRBD-Cluster 8.4.5 on 2 VM running ubuntu 14.04, following this example: http://geekpeek.net/configure-drbd-ubuntu/

Unfortunatelly I can not start the service. It seems to be either a network setup problem or maybe a incompatibility issue with 8.4.x on ubuntu 14.04

This is the msg I get:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/drbd start
 * Starting DRBD resources                                                                                    [
]
<1>bind(s->s_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &s->s_local, sizeof(s->s_local)) failed: -1 No such file or directory

<1>error creating netlink socket
..........
***************************************************************
 DRBD's startup script waits for the peer node(s) to appear.
 - In case this node was already a degraded cluster before the
   reboot the timeout is 30 seconds. [degr-wfc-timeout]
 - If the peer was available before the reboot the timeout will
   expire after 30 seconds. [wfc-timeout]
   (These values are for resource 'disk1'; 0 sec -> wait forever)
 To abort waiting enter 'yes' [ 120]:No response from the DRBD driver! Is the module loaded?
```

The config file

```
resource disk1
{
   startup {
   wfc-timeout 30;
   outdated-wfc-timeout 20;
   degr-wfc-timeout 30;
 }

net {
   cram-hmac-alg sha1;
   shared-secret sync_disk;
 }

syncer {
   rate 100M;
   verify-alg sha1;
 }

on node1 {               # Node1 defined
   device /dev/drbd0;
   disk /dev/sdb;                   # Device to use with DRBD
   address 192.168.57.120:7789;       # IP Address and port of Node1
   meta-disk internal;
 }

on node2 {               # Node2 defined
   device /dev/drbd0;
   disk /dev/sdb;                   # Device to use with DRBD
   address 192.168.57.130:7789;       # IP Address and port of Node2
   meta-disk internal;
 }
}
```

There is little to nothing to find on the net on how to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Do you had found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. After looking more into the topic I deciced to go with GlusterFS.